# Avoid webjob waiting when ingest small batch of data to azure data explorer

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer

I have a webjob receives site click events from azure event hub, then ingest those events into ADX.

```cs
public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger] EventData[] events, ILogger logger)
{
    // Process events
    try
    {
        var ingestResult = await _adxIngester.IngestAsync(events);
        if (!ingestResult) 
        {
            AppInsightLogError();
            logger.LogError();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        AppInsighLogError();
        logger.LogError()
    }
}
```

I've used [queue ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-ingest#queued-ingestion) and turned off `FlushImmediately` when ingesting to ADX, which enable batch ingestion. When events does not meet default IngestionBatch policy of 1000 events / 1GB data size, ADX waits [5 minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/kusto/concepts/batchingpolicy#details) until it return `Success` status, which makes `Run` also waits for that amount of time.

```cs
public async Task<bool> IngestAsync(...) 
{
    IKustoQueuedIngestClient client = KustoIngestFactory.CreateQueuedIngestClient(kustoConnectionString);

    var kustoIngestionProperties = new KustoQueuedIngestionProperties(databaseName: "myDB", tableName: "events")
    {
        ReportLevel = IngestionReportLevel.FailuresOnly,
        ReportMethod = IngestionReportMethod.Table,
        FlushImmediately = false
    };

    var streamIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
    var clientResult = await client.IngestFromStreamAsync(...);
    var ingestionStatus = clientResult.GetIngestionStatusBySourceId(streamIdentifier);

    while (ingestionStatus.Status == Status.Pending)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        ingestionStatus = clientResult.GetIngestionStatusBySourceId(streamIdentifier);
    }

    if (ingestionStatus.Status == Status.Failed) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Since I don't want my webjob to wait that long when there are not many events coming in, or simply QA is at work, I made the following changes:

- Don't `await` on `IngestAsync`, thus make `Run` a synchronous method
- Add parameter `Action onError` to `IngestAsync` and call it when ingest task fails. Call `AppInsightLogError()` and `logger.LogError()` inside `onError`, instead of return `false`
- Replace `IngestFromStreamAsync` with `IngestFromStream`

Basically, I want to ensure events reaches [Azure Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-ingest#queued-ingestion) and throws exception (if any) before I poll for ingest status, then exit `Run` method, and I don't have to wait for status polling, if anything fails then it will be log.

My question is:

- Is it a good practice to avoid webjob waits for minutes? If no, why ?
- If yes, is my solution good enough for this problem? Otherwise how
  should I do this?

Comment: Why dont you directly ingest from EH to ADX ?

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G I have to process raw events coming from event hub before ingest to ADX, plus I don't have streaming ingestion enabled atm.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ingesting small batches of data and wish to cut down on the ingestion batching times, please read the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/concepts/batchingpolicy
Ingestion Batching policy allows you to control the batching limits per database or table.

Comment: Dead link.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 0):

The ingestion is performed in few phases. One phase is done at the client side, and one phase is done at the server side:

1. The ingest client code you’re using is going to take your stream and upload it to a blob, and then it will send a message to a queue.
   Any exceptions thrown during that phase, will indeed be propagated to your code, which is why you should also use some try-catch block, where in the catch block you can log the error message as you suggested. 
   You can either use IngestFromStreamAsync with the await keyword, or use IngestFromStream. The first option is better if you’d like to release the worker thread and save resources. But choosing between those two doesn’t have anything to do with the polling. The polling is relevant to the second phase.
2. Kusto’s DataManagement component is constantly listening to messages in the queue, so as soon as it gets to your new message, it will read it and see some metadata information about the new ingestion request, such as the blob URI where the data is stored and such as the Azure table where failures/progress should be updated.
   That phase is done remotely by the server side, and you have an option to wait in your client code for each single ingestion and poll until the server completes the ingestion process. If there are any exceptions during that phase, then of course they won’t be propagated to your client code, but rather you’ll be able to examine the Azure table and see what happened.
   You can also decide to defer that status examination, and have it done in some other task.

Comment: So if my data end up in a blob (and later queue) which means I can safely fire and forget `_adxIngester.IngestAsync(events)` and if everything go well it will end up in ADX?

Comment: In the polling result phase, it is not recommend to set [```IngestionReportLevel.FailuresAndSuccesses```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-status#tracking-ingestion-status-kustoqueuedingestclient). Yet if I don't do so and use ```IngestionReportLevel.FailuresOnly``` then my ingest status forever stuck in ```Pending``` (if there are no errors). So I guess in my case, where I care about the ingestion status, I must use ```IngestionReportLevel.FailuresAndSuccesses``` ?

Answer (score 0):

- `IngestFromStreamAsync` upload your data to a blob and post a message to the Data Management input queue.It will not wait for aggregation time and the final state you will get is [Queued](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-status#status-enumeration).
- `FlushImmediately` defaults to false.
- If there isn't any additional processing, consider using the [Event Hub to Kusto connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub)

[Edited] responding to comments:

- Queued state indicate the blob is pending ingestion. You can track status by [show ingestion failures command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/ingestionfailures), [metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-metrics) and [ingestion logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-diagnostic-logs).
- Event hub connection goes through queued ingestion by default. It will use streaming ingestion only if it is set as policy on the database / table
- Some of the processing can be done on ADX, using ingestion mapping and update policy.

Comment: Thank you for follow up, I never get ```Queued``` status though, perhaps is because I used ```IngestionReportMethod.Table``` ?